# Number of ways for the Queen

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

**Optimizing Queen's Path Calculation on a Grid with Memoization**
I am working on a problem where I need to calculate the number of different ways a queen can move to the bottom-right corner of a n x m grid, starting from the top-left corner. The queen can move any number of cells down, right, or diagonally down-right in one move. I have written a C++ program for this, but I am looking to optimize it using memoization. I need help with improving the efficiency of my code.

Below is my current C++ implementation of the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int n = 3;
int m = 3;

std::vector<std::vector<long long>> dp(n, std::vector<long long>(m, 0));

void left_sums(int i, int j) {
    for (int k = 0; k < j; ++k) {
        dp[i][j] += dp[i][k];
    }
}

void top_sums(int i, int j) {
    for (int k = 0; k < i; ++k) {
        dp[i][j] += dp[k][j];
    }
}

void diag_sums(int i, int j) {
    for (int k = 1; k <= std::min(i, j); ++k) {
        dp[i][j] += dp[i - k][j - k];
    }
}

long long count_ways(int n, int m) {
    // The queen starts at the top-left corner
    dp[0][0] = 1;

    // Calculating the number of ways for each cell
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
            left_sums(i, j);
            top_sums(i, j);
            diag_sums(i, j);
        }
    }

    return dp[n - 1][m - 1];
}

int main() {
    std::cout << count_ways(n, m); // For n = 3, m = 3 answer is 22.
    return 0;
}
```

Request for Assistance
I am looking to optimize this code using memoization techniques to improve its performance. Any suggestions or advice on how to efficiently implement memoization for this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At a quick glance, I see you use `dp`, which I assume is your Dynamic Programming memoization. Is there a problem with it? Can you focus your question on the problem?

Comment: the problem is that it takes too much time. I use dp to build an answer but at every step, I have to O(n) operations, which gives me O(n^3) total time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I use dp to build an answer but at every step, I have to O(n) operations, which gives me O(n^3) total time.

You can fix that by adding some more arrays.

Currently, you have a single array `dp` such that `dp[i][j]` represents the total number of ways to get from (0, 0) to (i, j) in any sequence of moves.

I'd suggest augmenting this with three more arrays, one for each direction of the last move to land on a given cell. For example, `from_left[i][j]` represents the total number of ways to get from (0, 0) to (*i*, *j*) in any sequence of moves *that ends with a left-to-right move*.

The reason this is useful is that there are only two *kinds* of ways to land on (*i*, *j*+1) coming from the left:

- You can come via (*i*, *j*).

  - This means that you came from (0, 0) to (*i*, *j*) and then moved to (*i*, *j*+1). There are exactly `dp[i][j]` ways to do that.
- You can come directly via some square to the left of (*i*, *j*).

  - The number of ways to do this is the same as the number of ways to come to (*i*, *j*) from the left, because the only difference is that the last move goes one square further. So, that's `from_left[i][j]`.

And, likewise for the other directions.

So you can compute this in *O*(*mn*) time by writing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
    if (i == 0) {
      from_above[i][j] = 0;
    } else {
      from_above[i-1][j] = dp[i-1][j] + from_above[i-1][j];
    }

    if (j == 0) {
      from_left[i][j] = 0;
    } else {
      from_left[i][j] = dp[i][j-1] + from_left[i][j-1];
    }

    if (i == 0 || j == 0) {
      from_diag[i][j] = 0;
    } else {
      from_diag[i][j] = dp[i-1][j-1] + from_diag[i-1][j-1];
    }

    if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
      dp[i][j] = 1;
    } else {
      dp[i][j] = from_above[i][j] + from_left[i][j] + from_diag[i][j];
    }
  }
}
```

and then returning `dp[m-1][n-1]`.